# How to prevent text from displaying behind the search Icon

Tags: html, css

For self-study I'm trying to build a search fields, but I am experimenting two issues.

1.
When the text is to long, it is being displayed behind the search Icon.
How do i prevent this?

2.
why is there a space between the icon and the right border even though I added `right:0;`

relative CODE:

```
.search i{
position: absolute;    
top:50%;
right:0;
transform: translateY(-50%);
font-size: 35px;
color: dimgray;
background-color:green;
}
```

```css
.search-container{
    display:flex;
    width:70%;
}
.search{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.search input{
    height:50px;
    padding:4px 0 4px 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.search i{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    right:0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 35px;
    color: dimgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="search-container">
            <select class="name">
                <option value="Name-1">Name-1</option>
                <option value="Name-2">Name-2</option>
                <option value="Name-3">Name-3</option>
                <option value="Name-4">Name-4</option>
                <option value="Name-5">Name-5</option>
                <option value="Name-6">Name-6</option>
                <option value="Name-7">Name-7</option>
            </select>
            <div class="search">
                <input class="search-bar search" type="text" name="search" autofocus placeholder="You can search for a name.">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: To begin with, I would try making a separate div for the search icon.

Comment: At bob, In the link you provided the Icon is to the left a simple `padding-left` in the input field will solve the problem but not if is to the right.

Comment: `.search input{ padding: 4px 50px 4px 30px; box-sizing: border-box; } .search i { right: 10px; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can add a right `padding` to your input and set the `box-sizing` to `border-box`.
2. There is a space because the icon is **not** placed on the right relatively to the input, but **relative to the `<div class="search">`** because **it is its first positioned (not static) ancestor element**. And if you inspect it with your browser, your icon is where this `div` ends.

[image]

Here is the fixed snippet:

```css
.search-container{
    display:flex;
    width:70%;
}
.search{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.search input{
    height:50px;
    padding:4px 50px 4px 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.search i{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    right:10px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 35px;
    color: dimgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="search-container">
            <select class="name">
                <option value="Name-1">Name-1</option>
                <option value="Name-2">Name-2</option>
                <option value="Name-3">Name-3</option>
                <option value="Name-4">Name-4</option>
                <option value="Name-5">Name-5</option>
                <option value="Name-6">Name-6</option>
                <option value="Name-7">Name-7</option>
            </select>
            <div class="search">
                <input class="search-bar search" type="text" name="search" autofocus placeholder="You can search for a name.">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your modified code that I believe achieves what you are asking for.
I have removed a `search` class from your search input, as the parent node has the same class.

```css
.search-container{
    display:flex;
    width:70%;
}
.search{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.search:focus-within {
  outline-width: 1px;
  outline-color: rgb(166,200,255);
  outline-style: solid;
}

.search input{
    height:50px;
    width: 90%;
    padding:4px 0 4px 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

.search i{
    display: flex;
    width: 10%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 0 .5em 0 .5em;
    color: dimgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="search-container">
            <select class="name">
                <option value="Name-1">Name-1</option>
                <option value="Name-2">Name-2</option>
                <option value="Name-3">Name-3</option>
                <option value="Name-4">Name-4</option>
                <option value="Name-5">Name-5</option>
                <option value="Name-6">Name-6</option>
                <option value="Name-7">Name-7</option>
            </select>
            <div class="search">
                <input class="search-bar" type="text" name="search" autofocus placeholder="You can search for a name.">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://jsfiddle.net/Sadhana/2LHh9/:

```css
.search_box {
    background:url("http://png-5.findicons.com/files/icons/980/yuuminco/256/search.png");
    background-size:20px 20px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    padding-right: 20px !important;
    padding-top: 2px !important;
    padding-bottom: 2px !important;
    padding-left: 5px !important;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textbox search_box" name="keywords" placeholder="Search..." />
```